# Linear trend in SAS using contrast

Tags: regression, sas, contrasts

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of hours, and I could use some advice.

I have a linear regression model with two continuous predictors and a categorical one (with 4 levels). I want to test for a linear trend in the categorical variable, with the lowest level as the reference. I've gotten the answer in Stata and R, but I can ONLY get the answer in SAS if I use its default reference level (which would be 4). If I change the reference level to 1, I get a different answer.

Stata (F=18.56):

```
contrast {Age -3 -1 1 3}
```

R (F=18.56):

```
fit.contrast(model_A, "age_cat", c(-3, -1, 1, 3))
```

SAS (F=0.06):

```
proc glm data=data;
class age (ref='1');
model outcome=continuous1 continuous2 age / solution ss3;
contrast 'linear trend' age -3 -1 1 3;
run;
```

I figure that since I'm adjusting the reference category I have to adjust something else, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How exactly are the categories labeled?  By default, SAS-GLM orders categories in the design matrix by the sort order of the class variable.

Comment: Try `contrast 'linear trend' age -3 -1 1 3 / e;` and it will show you what contrast is actually being estimated

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I didn't know about the e option, that showed me that the code needs to be: `contrast 'linear trend' age -1 1 3 -3`

Comment: How did you get the F statistic in R ? I only have the t-value in the output